# Laravel blade undefined variable in multiple loops

Tags: php, laravel

Im building a laravel app

```
@foreach ($reviews as $review)
<div>
    @if ($review->child_id == null)
    ... display data  
    @else
    {{$review->child_id}}
        @while ($review->child_id)   // this line throws error
        ...display data
        @php
            //trying to instantiate variable again       
            $review = App\Review::where('id',$review->child_id); // this line doesnt work
        @endphp
        @endwhile
    @endif
</div>
@endforeach
```

Basically I cant access the $review->child_id property it throws this error

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$child_id (View: /var/www/html/projects/guest-book/resources/views/reviews/comment.blade.php) (View: /var/www/html/projects/guest-book/resources/views/reviews/comment.blade.php)

but if I var dump it is there and I used it in previous if statement and it works just fine there.

What I am trying to do is display comment section each comment has child and parent ids. 
If comment does not have child id it is displayed normally otherwise it is indented.

How can I re-instantiate the variable in blade and how come I cant access that property which was used before in the same blade?

dd($review) :

```
Review {#248 ▼
  #fillable: array:6 [▶]
  #dates: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:11 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "grav_url" => "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/25d755d39ba840f931b70f90cbd591eb?d=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2F&s=20"
    "full_name" => "user name"
    "review" => "answer"
    "ip_address" => "127.0.0.1"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "parent_id" => "0"
    "child_id" => "5"
    "user_id" => null
    "created_at" => "2018-01-29 14:09:16"
    "updated_at" => "2018-01-29 14:09:16"
  ]
  #original: array:11 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #forceDeleting: false
}
```

dd($reviews) all reviews are basically like the one above so I didnt open them.

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#242 ▼
  #total: 4
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#244 ▼
    #items: array:4 [▼
      0 => Review {#245 ▶}
      1 => Review {#246 ▶}
      2 => Review {#247 ▶}
      3 => Review {#248 ▶}
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 12
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://localhost:8000"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

Controller index method :

```
    public function show() {    
    $reviews = Review::
        where('deleted_at', NULL)
        ->where('parent_id', 0)
        ->paginate(12);
    return view('reviews.reviews', compact('reviews'));
}
```

Comment: Please show results of `{{ dd($reviews) }}`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin edited question

Comment: You've shown results for the first `$review` only.

Comment: it's array type use it like this $review['child_id']

Comment: @GauravGupta That one throws `Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as array `

Comment: could you please explain what is the use of while loop here??

Comment: @Sohel0415 Because the depth of comment replies is unknown so I will keep taking different comment until he has no children and indent all a bit.

Comment: try `@while ($review->child_id!=null)` and `$review = App\Review::where('id',$review->child_id)->first();`

Comment: in your case you don't need to use while loop

Comment: @Sohel0415 Tried that before also throws `undefined property error`

Comment: did you make it json at the time of sending ? if so then use json_decode($reviews,true)

Comment: @BilalAhmed could you explain why?

Comment: because child attribute has single value. there is no sub array or sub child. you can simply `echo $review->child_id`

Comment: @zerociudo see my answer, you need to check if object empty or not first

Comment: @zerociudo did you use json() at the time of sending it from backend?

Comment: @GauravGupta I did not I need to encode it first? If I use json encode or decode in backend `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`  is thrown

Comment: @zerociudo can you show your backend code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `review` is empty or not-

```
@else
   @while ($review!=null&&$review->child_id!=null)
      ...display data
   @php
        //trying to instantiate variable again       
        $review = App\Review::where('id',$review->child_id)->first(); 

   @endphp
   @endwhile
@endif
```

If you are using laravel 5.5, then you can use [optional()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-optional) helper method-

```
@while (optional($review)->child_id)
```

Comment: still getting undefined property error with optional function.

Comment: are you using laravel 5.5??

Comment: `"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "lcobucci/jwt": "^3.2"
    },`

Comment: what is your undefined property error?? please show the full error after using this optional and please show your controller code

Comment: The error is added to the question and I added controller code now

Comment: The error changed now to `Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/projects/guest-book/resources/views/reviews/comment.blade.php) (View: /var/www/html/projects/guest-book/resources/views/reviews/comment.blade.php)`

Comment: please try with my first code, the one without optional

Answer (score 1):

You need to check child_id  more explicitly

```
@foreach ($reviews as $review)
<div>
@if ($review->child_id == null)
... display data  
@else
{{$review->child_id}}
    @while (optional($review)->child_id)   // change the if
    ...display data
    @php
        //trying to instantiate variable again       
        $review = App\Review::where('id',$review->child_id)->first(); //add first
    @endphp
    @endwhile
@endif
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I am afraid this does not work still getting `undefined property error`.